# how to set post variable in the sql query to get difference between two dates

Tags: php, mysql, google-visualization

I set two variable in date format then i put it in the sql query to find data between two dates and to show them as column chart. But its not working. without script code it shows proper data but when i include script for column it doesn't display any output  any suggestion?

Here is the code:

```
<?php

 $user='root';
 $pass='';
 $db='mypro_bms';
 $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost',$user,$pass,$db);
 $count=0;

 if(isset($_POST['search'])){
 $txtStartDate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['txtStartDate']));;
 $txtEndDate  = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['txtEndDate']));;

 $q=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT blood_group, SUM(blood_bag) as sum FROM donate where date(donation_date)between'$txtStartDate' and '$txtEndDate' group by blood_group");
 $count=mysqli_num_rows($q);
 }
  ?>
  <html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

       function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['sum','blood_group'],

          <?php
          if ($count=="0") 
          {
            echo "No data";          }
            else
            {
              while ($row=$q->fetch_assoc()) {
               echo"['".$row['blood_group']."',".$row['sum']."],";
              }
            }
      ?>
       ]);
      var options = {
          title: 'Blood volume',
          is3D: true,

        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
      </script>
  </head>
```

Comment: should be like this?

Comment: okay. doing .then let you kniow

Comment: Sorry its showing an error...   mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,bool given @WhiteHat

Comment: as you told me to assign the date. i did it but its not working. could you please help me to get the right solution @JamesZ